# Is there any IDE available for old tool SCM?

Tags: version-control

Is there any IDE available to handle check-in, check-out and code review for old SCM tool CMVC ?

Ex:  Eclipse is a famous IDE where in plugins can be installed to work with SCM tools (eg GIT), likewise is there any IDE available for CMVC or any modern tools which supports CMVC?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are CMVC Plug-Ins available for Eclipse 4.2 and 4.3

However, in order to download the plug ins from IBM you need to contact the IBM Support Desk